# Stuck with Javascript! - How do I use an If statement to update an element and an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to build a shopping cart function for a project.

This is what I am being asked to do:

Inside the if statement, update the `orderTotal` element to display Total: $ and the sum of all the prices inside the `cartItems` array.

1) Under the IF statement I am then entering: `orderTotal.innerHTML = "Total: $"`
2) At this point I get stuck as I do not know how to add the sum of all prices in the array?

Please help!

```js
var cartItems = [];
var isTotalHidden = true;

var backpack = {
 name: "Backpack",
 price: 400
}

var camera = {
 name: "Camera",
 price: 300
}

function addToCart(item) {
 cartItems.push(item);
 document.getElementById("itemCounter").innerHTML = cartItems.length;
 showTotal();
}

function clickCart() {
 isTotalHidden = !isTotalHidden;
 showTotal();
}

function showTotal() {
 var orderTotal = document.getElementById("orderTotal");
 orderTotal.innerHTML = "";
 
 if (isTotalHidden === false) {
  
 }
}
```

Comment: "Stuck with JavaScript"... great opening statement when asking questions of people who enjoy JavaScript and are taking time to help you with your work.

Comment: In addition to the answer to your question below... some advice... don't use elements by ID.  It clutters up the global namespace, and hasn't been necessary in a very long time.  Additionally, don't set the text content of the element via `innerHTML`.  Use `textContent` instead.  Otherwise, you'll be bitten some day by invalid HTML or potential XSS issues.  Finally, format your numbers when setting the text content of those fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Array.reduce like this:

```js
var backpack = {
 name: "Backpack",
 price: 400
}

var camera = {
 name: "Camera",
 price: 300
}

cart = [camera, backpack]
console.log(cart.reduce((agg,cur) => agg + cur.price,0))
```

What reduce does in its basic form (which is sufficient for your use case) is takes two arguments callback and starting value (in your case 0). Callback than has two arguments (aggregator and current). You than sum previously aggregated value with the current one in each iteration.

More on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

I assume you dont know how to access properties of objects?
As example:
to get the price of the camera (which is a JS [objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)) you need to either use the property-name like this `objectName.propertyName` so `camera.price` or this `objectName["propertyName"]` so `camera["price"]`

I think with this knowledge you can awnser the question yourself rather than copy/pasting someone elses code and learning nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your cartItems array has objects that have price property. In your ShowTotal function you can loop over cartItems and save the price of each item. Let me show you

```
function showTotal() {
  var orderTotal = document.getElementById("orderTotal");
  //initialize sum to zero
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; cartItems.length; i++) {
    //add price of each item to sum
    sum = sum + cartItems[i].price; 
  }
 orderTotal.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help.

```
function showTotal() {
 var orderTotal = document.getElementById("orderTotal");
 orderTotal.innerHTML = "";

 if (isTotalHidden === false) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cartItems.length;i++){
    total += cartItems[i].price;
  }
  orderTotal.innerHTML += "Total: $" + total;
 }
}
```

Comment: It would help considerably if you included an explanation of what your code does and, on an old question with old answers, what benefits it brings compared to the other answers already given.